# Formula to get frame display number after seek in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

For a given AV file, I need to be able to seek to a particular video frame number in the file.  Because of how decoding works, I am seeking to the nearest I-Frame *before* the required frame (which may or may not be the requested frame) and then decoding the frames in the GOP until I get to where I need to be. As such, I need to know my current position after seeking.

Having found some posts of a similar nature on *SO*, I've gone away and collected a few interesting samples to see if I can get a formula to work across many different files, but I'm having a hard time. What works or 1 file may not work for another:

File #1 (Podbox)

Requested to seek to fame #1500. First video frame reports:

```
AVFrame::pts = 760320
AVFrame::pkt_duration = 512

AVStream::time_base = {1,12800}
AVStream::start_time = 0
AVStream::avg_frame_rate = {25,1}
```

File #2 (HTE54959)

Requested to seek to fame #1500. First video frame reports:

```
AVFrame::pts = 1500
AVFrame::pkt_duration = 1

AVStream::time_base = {1,25}
AVStream::start_time = 0
AVStream::avg_frame_rate = {25,1}
```

File #3 (BuckBunny)

Requested to seek to fame #1800. First video frame reports:

```
AVFrame::pts = 1563562
AVFrame::pkt_duration = 1001

AVStream::time_base = {1,30000}
AVStream::start_time = 0
AVStream::avg_frame_rate = {30000,1001}
```

File #4 (HouseDance)

Requested to seek to fame #1800. First video frame reports:

```
AVFrame::pts = 1800
AVFrame::pkt_duration = 1

AVStream::time_base = {1001,30000}
AVStream::start_time = 0
AVStream::avg_frame_rate = {30000,1001}
```

For the above files, the following members are *always* zero:

```
AVFrame::coded_picture_number
AVFrame::display_picture_number
```

I have thought about merely using AVFrame::pts / AVFrame::pkt_duration, but I'm not sure that is the right way of doing things. I know for some codecs, there can be a variable frame rate (VFR) which would mean that my method is erroneous? I assume that the AVFrame::pkt_duration could change per AVFrame?

I want to emphasize that my issue is not being able to seek. I am seeking to the correct location - I have verified that visually using timecode. My issue is programmatically identifying the frame number of the seek position

Using FFmpeg v4.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most formats and ffmpeg don't keep track of absolute frame indexes. Timestamp is the benchmark.

There are two workarounds:

#1 Remux to MP4 or MOV and then seek. The demuxer will print a trace level log.

```
stream 0, found sample 320
```

This is the nearest prior keyframe.

#2 Decode all frames from start and count :(

Comment: Thanks @Gyan. You hit the nail on the head. I need to think about this in terms of timestamps and not frames.